# Highcharts Progress bar with % values and Y axis to be as Date values

Tags: highcharts

I'm new to High Charts and working on an example with the Data on the Y-axis as Date component with the Start and End Dates and the X Axis will be of type with the 'Bar' chart

Here is the link of my example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/venkyramvr/5mLv2ss6/)

The series data would be something like this

```
'series: [{
            name: '',
            low: Date.UTC(2016, 07, 01),
            high: Date.UTC(2017, 04, 04)
        }'
```

Any helps on this would be highly appreciated

Updated on 03/04/2017 for the Image attachment

[image]

Here the bars going beyond the End Date time

Comment: If I understand correctly here is a simplified solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/73325s7p/

Set xAxis.type to datetime.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking at all. What part of this are you having trouble with? What about your fiddle is not doing what you want? However, it sounds like you may be looking for the `columnrange` series type, which can be used horizontally if you set `inverted: true` in your chart object.  Ref:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted | http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange

Comment: @stpoa, Thanks for your help and it is similar to what i needed, but the Bars should be independent of each and Each bar should have start and end date times, 
Also is it possible to have the Name to be displayed inside the Bar

Comment: @jlbriggs, Sorry i'm not much clear on my example and sorry for it.

What i'm trying to have a Date on Yaxis (Start and End) and the bars inside the chart or depenending on the start and end date of the Axis and sometimes it can go beyond of those dates which will be showing as % of the bars

Comment: Maybe what you want is columnrange chart: https://jsfiddle.net/v8jg6tx3/, if not please attach an image of how your chart should look like

Comment: @stpoa, I have attached the image in the main thread. Thanks in advance